# How can I directly display a simple .OSM file in browser?

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

How can I directly display a simple .OSM file in browser. I want to simply display .OSM file in the browser like it is displayed in JOSM editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Leaflet plugin [leaflet-osm](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/leaflet-osm) has the option to load a data layer which uses a single OSM object, or a small number of objects. This method is not recommended for a large amount of data.

Here's the example from the leaflet page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/164979149",
  // or "http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/52477381/full"
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
    var layer = new L.OSM.DataLayer(xml).addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display osm as vector data by using the leaflet plugin [leaflet-osm](https://github.com/jfirebaugh/leaflet-osm) for example.

Answer (score 0):

That is not directly possible because the [.osm file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) is just a XML file containing raw data, it needs to be rendered first. However there is various [rendering software](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering), some of it can produce an image directly out of a .osm file.